# Потоки. Асинхронная передача данных. Помогите разобраться.

Tags: winapi, winsock, c++

Делаю программу отправки/приема данных на сервер, и решил сделать её асинхронной. Читаю много форумов, но пока не совсем понимаю последовательность действий.

Вот смотрите - делаю поток командой CreateEvent(...). Далее я должен создать сокет, или все же "ветку" (thread[0] = CreateThread(...)) в которой уже создавать сокет? И если я захочу сделать второй поток, то мне надо будет создавать вторую ветку thread[1] = CreateThread(...)? Или еще один Event?

Плюс у сокетов есть свой WSACreateEvent, и в инете видел, что создают Event, потом Thread, потом в этом Thread создают WSACreateEvent... Вопрос - для чего?
Сможете объяснить?:)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[CreateEvent](http://www.firststeps.ru/mfc/msdn/r.php?83) не создает поток. Эта функция создает событие, на которые поток может реагировать и синхронизировать себя с другими потоками. Т.е. это что-то вроде локера для доступа к данным.

Дальше, сокет вы можете создать как в треде, так и вне его. Если вам нужно обращаться к сокету в нескольких потоках, то выносите его за пределы треда. Если только один поток будет работать с ним, то есть смысл спрятать сокет внутрь. Чтобы создать второй поток, нужно снова вызывать CreateThread.

[WSACreateEvent](http://sources.ru/cpp/cpp_network_evets_winsock2.shtml) - используется для асинхронной работы с сокетами. Т.е. программа может быть как-бы "однопоточная", но при определенных событиях (например на асинхронный сокет приходит месадж), вызывается функция программы, асигнованная с этим евентом.

А вообще, советую больше почитать на тему сокетов, потоков и евентов. В инете полно инфы. Лучше искать ответы не на форумах, а в msdn или каких-то самоучителях и онлайн-руководствах.

Comment: В том и дело, что msdn это уже чуть ли не наизусть знаю, но почему-то не могу в общую картину всё собрать.

Comment: И да, спасибо огромное, стало уже более понятно. Кстати вот мой же вопрос, но я там больше объяснил, что не понятно: http://borland.xportal.ru/forum/viewtopic.php?p=120396#120396

То есть, получается, я могу создать Событие, сразу же создать Тред1 и в него запихнуть сокет, работающий на протяжении всей программы, и создавать тред2 с сокетом, что бы отправить-принять сообщение? Или создать Событие, запихнуть сокет, и отдельно тредом создавать/удалять второй сокет?

Comment: И ещё по треду - не совсем понимаю, что четвертым параметром ему передавать надо. В инете все передают какую-то структуру. Для чего она?

Comment: Хотя по последнему вопросу - смотрю, что некоторые просто 0 передают.

Comment: Читайте документацию, или вспоминайте, вы же наизусть знаете msdn..

Comment: Почти сразу нашел потом, так что уже не надо.